# Running Cordova via a shell script - permission problem

Tags: php, bash, cordova, sh, macos-catalina

I have a shell script (called test.sh) which is called from PHP. Within the script I simply have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(whoami)
cordova platform version ios
```

If I call test.sh from within terminal it works fine and returns the cordova ios version.

If I try to call test.sh from with PHP I get:

```
cordova: not found
```

I have altered apache to run under my username instead of _www but that hasnt worked.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I'm guessing it is a permissions issue?

---

I have now simplified it further by removing the .sh file and just using the PHP script (under user _www)

```
exec('echo $(whoami) 2>&1', $output, $return_var); 
print_r($output);
echo "<br><br>"; 

putenv("CORDOVA_HOME=/usr/local/bin/cordova");
exec('cordova -v 2>&1', $output, $return_var); 
print_r($output);
```

Note: whoami works fine but corvoda is still not found.

Comment: in your terminal , type "which cordova"

Comment: which cordova returns /usr/local/bin/cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I looked at the path returned from terminal and PHP, they were both using the same username but returned different path details.

After adding to PHP:

```
putenv("PATH=".getenv('PATH').":/Users/USERNAME/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands");

putenv("CORDOVA_HOME=/usr/local/bin/cordova");
```

It began to work. I now have a problem with finding certificates but that will be a different question after investigating it.

Answer (score 0):

Use npm to install Cordova globally. right now Cordova is not available in your host globally. So make it globally first.

on OS X and Linux:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

on Windows:

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: Tried this OS X (catalina) and no luck. I've run httpd.conf under _www and USERNAME.

Comment: how are you running the bashScript though  PHP ?

Comment: PHP: exec('/Users/USER/scripts/test.sh 2>&1', $output, $return_var); then in the script:   #!/bin/bash cordova platform version ios. but have also tried /usr/local/bin/cordova platform version ios

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention after trying the uninstall/install I got the message env: node: No such file or directory when running the script. I have tried to uninstall node and install -g but the message remains.

Comment: Several possibilities:

You have safe mode enabled. That way, only exec() is working, and then only on executables in safe_mode_exec_dir
exec and shell_exec are disabled in php.ini
The path to the executable is wrong. If the script is in the same directory as the php file, try exec(dirname(__FILE__) . '/myscript.sh');

Comment: After a reboot the env:node error stopped but the cordova: not found returned. Is /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova the correct location for global install?

Comment: FYI it is PHP 7.3.11 so safe_mode does nothing. but I have added it anyway just incase