# PHP exec works in terminal but not via URL

Tags: php, macos, cordova, macos-catalina

I have got a PHP file which runs fine in Terminal (PHP /Users/xxx/Sites/upload.php).

Within this it runs :

```
 exec('cordova -v 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
 or
 exec('/usr/local/bin/cordova -v 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
 print_r($output);
```

If I then run this same php file via a browser (same machine) it fails reporting cordova not found.

I have tried putenv("CORDOVA_HOME=/usr/local/bin/cordova"); and setting httpd.conf to USER = USERNAME & GROUP = _www but I'm not sure if this is correct, they were both previously _www.
PHP is version PHP 7.3.11 and it is running on Mac catalina

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: And what account does you web server run under? Probably not your user account

Comment: Did you check the Error Logs? For some clues

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/cordova -v 2>&1` maybe?

Comment: The only error I get is 'cordova: command not found', this is also in the logs. The apache runs under _www so it looks like a conflict with permissions because in terminal under USERNAME it works fine. I have changed httpd.conf to USER = USERNAME but left GROUP = _www and it failed. Do I need to also alter GROUP, if so what to?

Comment: Solved link to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154071/running-cordova-via-a-shell-script-permission-problem

Answer (score 0):

CLI and FPM are using different configurations usually. check your PHP FPM configuration for `safe_mode_exec_dir` and related.

> > https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir

Comment: I have looked in /php-fpm.d/www.conf.defaulf and user + group were set to nobody. Should these get wet to _www or USERNAME? and should the www.conf.default be renamed to www.conf?  also safe_mode_exec_dir is not within www.conf.default as im running PHP 7.3.11 and it was removed in 5.4 .                                                              As a test I set the httpd.conf (apache) and and www.conf (php) to the same USERNAME and GROUPNAME (my username and group) but no joy...

Comment: I checked PATH for the same user from terminal and php and they appeard different so i added putenv("PATH=".getenv('PATH').":/Users/usertest/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands"); to the PHP file. This now allows cordova to run but produced the error [throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);] from php but works in termainl

Comment: true. in the initial question you said you are using the path, not just the command. this would exclude the environment path problems.

Comment: validate that the params you pass are similar and valid. if it works with the CLI version there should be the error then.